# CallKit issue with call holding (iOS 10)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, callkit

I have an issue with CallKit API on iOS 10.3.3 and lower iOS versions.

My configuration supports call holding and grouping, here is the snippet.

```
let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: applicationName)

configuration.supportsVideo = supportsVideo
configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]
configuration.maximumCallGroups = 2
configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 3
```

On iOS 10, CallKit drops the call when app requests setHeld action for call.
Here is the snippet of setHeld call action request.

```
public func performSetCallOnHoldAction(_ call: Call, isOnHold: Bool) {
   let setHeldAction = CXSetHeldCallAction(call: UUID(uuidString: call.callUUID)!, onHold: isOnHold)
   let transaction = CXTransaction()
   transaction.addAction(setHeldAction)

   requestTransaction(transaction)
}
```

And finally, here is the CXProvider delegate method, which completes the hold/unhold action for call:

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetHeldCallAction) {

    // Retrieve the Call instance corresponding to the action's call UUID
    guard let call = CallList.sharedInstance().call(withUUID: action.callUUID.uuidString) else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }

    // Perform PJSUA set held action
    if action.isOnHold {
        Pjsua2Wrapper.sharedInstance()?.holdCall(withCallUUID: call.callUUID, completion: { (error) in
            (error != nil) ? action.fail() : action.fulfill()
        })
    } else {
        Pjsua2Wrapper.sharedInstance()?.unholdCall(withCallUUID: call.callUUID, completion: { (error) in
            (error != nil) ? action.fail() : action.fulfill()
        })
    }
}
```

Note that I use Pjsip to perform a hold/unhold action and inside a completion block I call `action.fulfill(`) or `action.fail()`, depending wether psjip returns the error.

In application GUI, there is a toggle swap button, which calls function to perform `CXSetHeldCallAction` on `CXCallController`.

On iOS 11.0 everything works perfectly, but on iOS 10, when you press that toggle button, the call which is supposed to be set on hold, gets ended by the `CXProvider` for some reason (`CXProvider` responds with `CXEndCallAction`).

I have looked in debugger for `requestTransaction` method wether it returns transaction error, but there is no error in requesting a transaction to call controller.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong, or something that I can try out to fix this issue?

Comment: Anyone have an answer here?? I have same problem but for iOS 12.